# authorize.net json return extra characters

Tags: php, json, authorize.net

I have this code

```
$ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'"));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data_str));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  $xmlresult = curl_exec($ch);
  $xmlError = $xmlresult;
  $json = json_decode($xmlresult, true);
```

The answer I get into json but I could not convert because the in the beginning answer is, extra characters See example

```
п»ї{"customerPaymentProfileIdList":[],"customerShippingAddressIdList":[],"validationDirectResponseList":[],"messages":{"resultCode":"Error","message":[{"code":"E00039","text":"A duplicate record with ID 39223758 already exists."}]}}
```

response header

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Cache-Control: private
>   Content-Length: 232
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT,OPTIONS,POST,GET
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with,cache-control,content-type,origin,method,SOAPAction
>   Date: Thu, 04 Feb 2016 09:08:15 GMT
>   Connection: keep-alive

Because of the extra characters I can not json_decode string. What can be done?

Comment: Its almost 2019 and this behavior still persists when using Authorize.net API endpoints (validated against `https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api`).

Comment: I believe Authorize.Net's responses are encoded in `utf-8-sig`. I don't use PHP, but if you account for the encoding it should simply work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same issue when developing my [library for accessing their JSON API](https://github.com/stymiee/authnetjson). In [the code that handles the response](https://github.com/stymiee/authnetjson/blob/master/src/authnet/AuthnetJsonResponse.php) I had to strip those characters out in order to properly decode the string as JSON.

**Line 113:**

```
$this->responseJson = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $responseJson);
```

Comment: I see this regex a lot. Should it really be stripping out any number of these characters, in any order, through the whole JSON string? Should it not just be looking at the first three characters? `'/^[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]{3,3}/'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue in Node.js with `JSON.parse()`.

```
var https = require('https');
var requestData = {
  "getCustomerProfileIdsRequest": {
    "merchantAuthentication": {
      "name": "your-auth-name-here",
      "transactionKey": "your-trans-key-name-here"
    }
  }
};
var requestString = JSON.stringify(requestData);
var req = https.request({
  host: "apitest.authorize.net",
  port: "443",
  path: "/xml/v1/request.api",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Length": requestString.length,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
});

req.on('response', function (resp) {
  var response = '';

  resp.setEncoding('utf8');
  resp.on('data', function(chunk) {
    response += chunk;
  });
  resp.on('end', function() {
    var buf = new Buffer(response);
    console.log('buf[0]:', buf[0]); // 239 Binary 11101111
    console.log('buf[0] char:', String.fromCharCode(buf[0])); // "ï"
    console.log('buf[1]:', buf[1]); // 187 Binary 10111011
    console.log('buf[1] char:', String.fromCharCode(buf[1])); // "»"
    console.log('buf[2]:', buf[2]); // 191 Binary 10111111
    console.log('buf[2] char:', String.fromCharCode(buf[2])); // "¿"
    console.log('buf[3]:', buf[3]); // 123
    console.log('buf[3] char:', String.fromCharCode(buf[3])); // "{"

    // Note: The first three chars are a "Byte Order Marker" i.e. `BOM`, `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`, `11101111 10111011 10111111`

    response = JSON.parse(response); // Throws error: 'Unrecoverable exception. Unexpected token SyntaxError: Unexpected token'
    console.log(response);
  });
});
req.on('error', function (error) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});

req.on('socket', function(socket) {
  socket.on('secureConnect', function() {
    req.write(requestString);
    req.end();
  });
});
```

If I call `trim()` on the response, it works:

```
response = JSON.parse(response.trim());
```

Or replace the `BOM`:

```
response = response.replace(/^\uFEFF/, '');
response = JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: See: https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/json-decode-return-NULL/m-p/53696#M28790

Comment: See: https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/JSON-issues/m-p/48851/highlight/true#M24533